# Positive tags not working in Cucumber 1.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber

I'm trying to run features/scenarios with tags, but I'm getting an error when I run the positive version of the tag.  It seems that the negative version of the tags work just fine. I'm not sure if it matters, but I'm running this on Windows.

When I run `bundle exec cucumber --tags @focus` I get this set of errors:

```
missing argument: --tags (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/cli/options.rb:119:in `parse!'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:25:in `parse!'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:55:in `configuration'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:63:in `run_drb_client'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:34:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby193/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

When I run `bundle exec cucumber --tags ~@focus` everything works just fine.

Here's my `cucumber.yml` config file:

```
<%
rerun = File.file?('rerun.txt') ? IO.read('rerun.txt') : ""
rerun_opts = rerun.to_s.strip.empty? ? "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'progress'} features" : "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} #{rerun}"
std_opts = "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} --strict --tags ~@wip"
%>
default: <%= std_opts %> features
wip: --tags @wip:3 --wip features
rerun: <%= rerun_opts %> --format rerun --out rerun.txt --strict --tags ~@wip
```

Here's what I'm using in my `Gemfile.rb`:

```
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

gem "rspec-rails"
gem "capybara"
gem "factory_girl_rails"
gem "cucumber", "1.2.5"
gem "cucumber-rails", "1.3.0", :require => false
gem "database_cleaner"
```

I suspect that this issue has something to do with the config file.  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: If you use `-t` instead of `--tags` do you get the same problem?

Comment: Yes - I get the same behavior for `-t`

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue on windows, I resolved this by putting quotes around the tag name

```
bundle exec cucumber --tags '@focus'
```